# removing all files except a group in bash

Tags: arrays, bash

I want to remove all files, but the one that I have in a list. Let's say for the sake of argument that these files are in a array. The array only contains the last three digits of the file, without the extension. all files are extension jpg. This is what I've been trying to do. Files name are in the form of GEDC1227.JPG

```
pics=(227 222 231 248 252 253 255 272 274 278)
for line in *; do 
 for j in $pics[@]; do 
  [[ ${line:5:3} == $j ]] && break
 done
 rm $line
done
```

I'm aware that there are easier ways to accomplish this; however, I'm kind of intrigue, why my algorithm is not working. I think is because is getting to the rm $line every time, and I haven't found a way to bypass that line when test condition is true (which is for files that I don't want remove)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to continue twice i.e. resume the next iteration of the outer loop:

```
pics=(227 222 231 248 252 253 255 272 274 278)
for line in *; do 
    for j in "${pics[@]}"; do 
        [[ ${line:5:3} == "$j" ]] && continue 2
    done
    rm -- "$line"
done
```

- Adding quotes to `${pics[@]}`. Not really necessary but it's a good practice to prevent word splitting when elements expand.
- Quoted second argument to `==` to prevent interpreting it as a glob pattern.
- Added `--` to `rm` to prevent trying to read files starting with `-` as option and cause an error to `rm`.

This alternative solution may also apply but needs testing:

```
shopt -s extglob
shopt -s nullglob
echo rm -- ?????!(227|222|231|248|252|253|255|272|274|278)*
```

Remove `echo` if found correct.

`continue` from bash manual:

> continue: continue [n]
>
> Resume for, while, or until loops.
>
> Resumes the next iteration of the enclosing FOR, WHILE or UNTIL loop.
>   If N is specified, resumes the Nth enclosing loop.

Comment: what does the 2 after "continue" statement does? does it skip to the outer loop?

Answer (score 0):

I would also consider doing this without a loop at all.

Something like this can be made to run in parallel and won't choke (like a glob might) if there are many files in the directory.

```
pics=( 227 222 231 248 252 253 255 272 274 278 )

# convert the array to a regex that matches GEDC.227\.JPG$|GEDC.222\.JPG$|...
keep="$( echo "GEDC.${pics[@]}\\.JPG$" | sed -e 's: :\\.JPG$|GEDC.:g' )"

find -type f -iname GEDC*.jpg \
  | egrep -v "$keep" \
  | xargs rm
```